# ¿Cómo puedo validar la extensión y el peso de imagenes en PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario POST donde se adjuntan 5 imágenes, 2 de estas son requeridas y 3 opcionales (las dos requeridas lo solucione directamente en el form con la etiqueta required) , los tipos de imagen requeridos son [png, jpeg, jpg] que no superen *1 Mb* por imagen. Como solo 2 de las imágenes son obligatorias, se entiende que algunos de esos campos se irán vacíos, lo que me hace imaginar que el primer paso es validar cuantos de esos campos van con archivo, he intentado muchas opciones para 1. validar que campos van con información, 2. validar la extensión para asegurarse que se trata de una imagen y 3. validar el peso de los archivos para que no supere 1mb por cada uno, tengo algo como esto:

```
$tipo_archivo = $_FILES['image1']['type'];
$tamano_archivo = $_FILES['image1']['size'];

    if (!((strpos($tipo_archivo, "gif") || strpos($tipo_archivo, "jpeg") || strpos($tipo_archivo, "png")) && ($tamano_archivo < 2000000))){
    header("location:failimg.php");
}
```

**PERO:** Esto va bien si se tratara de una sola imagen... pero como se trata de 2 a 5 imágenes, hacer esta validación variable por variable me deja muchas lineas de código que ademas no funciona, muestra ("`location:failimg.php`") pero no da pistas de absolutamente nada.

Comment: ¿No termino de entender el tema de las extensiones?, lo digo por que mencionas 5 imágenes pero en tu pregunta solo especificas 4 extensiones, ¿podrías ampliar ahi?

Comment: La idea es que el usuario suba archivos de imagen exclusivamente, los que menciono son los que creo son mas comunes. BMP creo que ya no se usa o no se, he visto varios códigos pero no logro entenderlos y no se como hacerlos funcionar, ni siquiera identifico donde esta el error

Comment: con cualquiera de los formatos ahi indicados cierto?

Comment: si, lo importante es que si o si, sea un archivo tipo imagen

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener datos como los que mencionas, su extensión y nombres...
Puedes usar [`path_info`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.pathinfo.php):

```
<?php
$partes_ruta = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $partes_ruta['dirname'], "\n";  // /www/htdocs/inc
echo $partes_ruta['basename'], "\n"; // lib.inc.php
echo $partes_ruta['extension'], "\n";// php
echo $partes_ruta['filename'], "\n"; // lib.inc 
?>
```

Y para el tamaño, pues [`filesize`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filesize.php)

```
$nombre_fichero = 'fichero.txt';
echo $nombre_fichero . ': ' . filesize($nombre_fichero) . ' bytes';
```

Luego de ello, puedes guardar el dato en una variable y compararlo con una simple condición `IF`

```
if($partes_ruta['extension'] === "jpg"){
    // Entras al if con una extension jpg
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu intervención, pero estas copiando y pegando del manual, el manual no lo comprendo del todo ya que soy demasiado nuevo en esto, no he logrado hacer funcionar algo como: if filesize (lo que este en el post) > 2mb, creo que la estructura no esta mal, pero no se como iria la sintaxis.

Comment: Bueno, si no entiendes como funciona, primero úsalo en un archivo para que obtengas sus resultados. Los resultados son obtenidos en bytes, por lo que la comparación es del mismo modo. [ejemplo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filesize.php#120250)

Comment: Vale, gracias, pero creo que no me hice entender, Edito la pregunta a ver si logro ser claro.

Comment: Agregaste que tu codigo no funciona, pero no has pegado el codigo que no funciona. Solo hay un trozo de validaciones.

Answer (score 0):

te comparto la forma en la que lo hago a la hora de manejar imagenes
`$imagen = $_File['imagen'];`
utilizo la funcion `is_uploaded_file()` para comprobar que exista una imagen y no venga vacio, luego utilizo una condicion para validar la extension

```
if($imagen["type"] == "jpg" or $imagen["type"] == "jpeg"){
 //si coincide hace algo
}else{

}
```

y lo mismo seria para el tamaño de la imagen

```
if($imagen["size"] > 1000000){
 throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.'); //excepcion al sobrepasar el limite
}
```